# Is there way to convert string jsx to React component level in react native?

Tags: parsing, react-native

I'm trying to convert "hello" string from a some server to be rendered in React Native.

But even after removing quotes, it is not rendered. The type of the "hello" even after quotes removed is 'string'. It seems 'object' has to be inserted to the render function.

Is there any way we can try this out? Looking at Expo examples, the web client receives the lines of codes that essentially produces the actual app, I think there might be some way around.

Please share any thought with me!

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe it is easier to take the “Hello” string and create a jsx object like:

```
render() {
     const hello = “Hello”; 
     return (<span> {hello} </span> );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But in this case, the jsx string might be way more complex. For instance, <View><View><TouchableOpacity brbr></TouchableOpacity><Text>asdf</Text></View> case will take many logical operations in order to create reat component. But that will be demanding work. I am wondering whether jsx string can easily be turned into the components level.